# Is there a way to import an embedded python script into IronPython as a python module?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I have an embedded resource in my dll which is a python script. I'd like to make the classes and functions in that resource available to the python engine, so I can execute external .py files (as `__main__`) which would be able to do something like

```
import embedded_lib # where embedded_lib is an embedded python script
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? I was hoping there will be some sort of `IronPython.ImportModule('module_name', source)` so I've looked through IronPython docs and couldn't find anything, but I'm hoping I'm just bad at looking.. Maybe there is some way to intercept a call to `import` and load my script that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You just need to add search paths to ScriptEngine object like this:

```
var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(yourLibsPath); // add directory to search
```

or

```
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

Then you could use any module in directories, which you add:

```
import pyFileName # without extension .py
```

**Update**
OK. If you want to use embedded resource strings like module, you may use this code:

```
var scope = engine.CreateScope(); // Create ScriptScope to use it like a module
engine.Execute("import clr\n" +
                "clr.AddReference(\"System.Windows.Forms\")\n" +
                "import System.Windows.Forms\n" + 
                "def Hello():\n" +
                "\tSystem.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(\"Hello World!\")", scope); // Execute code from string in scope.
```

Now you have a ScriptScope object (**scope** in code) containing all executed functions. And you may insert them into another scope like this:

```
foreach (var keyValuePair in scope.GetItems())
{
    if(keyValuePair.Value != null)
        anotherScope.SetVariable(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

Or you can execute your scripts right in this ScriptScope:

```
dynamic executed = engine.ExecuteFile("Filename.py", scope);
executed.SomeFuncInFilename();
```

And in this script you may use all functions without **import**:

```
def SomeFuncInFilename():
    Hello() # uses function from your scope
```

Comment: Oh sorry, you whant to use modules from embedded resource... Then I think you may try to execute your embedded resource modules with engine.Execute(string, ScriptScope) and then use its ScriptScope in another executing scripts or files. Or you can always create a temp file with your resource text and use search paths :)

Comment: Update your answer accordingly if you think it is answering the question. Add the code to explain it, if needed..

Comment: Seems to be working so far, thanks! (Easier than I thought it'd be!)

Comment: Is it possible to really use it as a module (I mean *with* the *import* keyword?)